# Why does appending n to a number (to create a BigInt) result in an error?

Tags: javascript, bigint

I am writing a program to return the index of the first number in the fibonacci sequence that has a given length of digits.

appending n to the number in the function call results in the following:

```js
let fibIdxByLength = (length) => {
  let [ cur, next ] = [ 1n, 1n ];
  let idx = 2n;
  while (next < (10 ** (length - 1))) {
    [ cur, next ] = [ next, cur + next ];
    idx++;
  }
  return idx;
};

fibIdxByLength(2n) === 7n; // 1 1 2 3 5 8 13
fibIdxByLength(3n)  === 12n;  // 1 1 2 3 5 8 13 21 34 55 89 144
fibIdxByLength(10n) === 45n;
fibIdxByLength(16n) === 74n;
fibIdxByLength(100n) === 476n;
fibIdxByLength(10000n) === 4782n;
```

this results in: Identifier directly after number and the program won't run

I've also tried using BigInt() instead but it says BigInt is undefined.

Any ideas?

Comment: The error message is fairly clear. Especially if you look it up. A BigInt and a normal number are incompatible `length - 1` is not an allowed operation. `length - 1n` is. You need to make sure you're only operating on BigInts or normal numbers, not a mix of the two.

Comment: Just a remark: why recalculating `10**(length-1)` repeatedly?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why BigInt() doesn't work (it at least works for me when I ran and debugged this in the Chrome console, it showed me that it didn't like when you were doing (length - 1). This is because length was a BigInt type, while 1 is a normal integer type. The same happened with the 10. I made them both BigInt types and it seems to work.

```js
let fibIdxByLength = (length) => {
  let [ cur, next ] = [ 1n, 1n ];
  let idx = 2n;
  while (next < (10n ** (length - 1n))) {
    [ cur, next ] = [ next, cur + next ];
    idx++;
  }
  return idx;
};

fibIdxByLength(2n) === 7n; // 1 1 2 3 5 8 13
fibIdxByLength(3n)  === 12n;  // 1 1 2 3 5 8 13 21 34 55 89 144
fibIdxByLength(10n) === 45n;
fibIdxByLength(16n) === 74n;
fibIdxByLength(100n) === 476n;
fibIdxByLength(10000n) === 4782n;
```

Comment: "*I'm not sure why BigInt() doesn't work*" because you cannot operate on a BigInt and a normal number at the same time. The operation is unsafe, lossy, and error prone - e.g., `0.5 * 1n` will produce what? A BigInt? A normal number? If it's a BigInt, then it cannot be "half" of something that doesn't have a concept for half. If it's a normal number do you leave it? Round to the nearest integer? What is the nearest integer? It's more complex when you start getting out of bounds of normal number safe values.

Comment: I made the changes you suggested and i'm still getting the same error. Even if I comment out all code and simply type something like: let x=2n, it produces the same error. Could it be something in VScode?

Comment: VLAZ, I meant that BigInt() WAS working for me when, as you said I modified the code to ONLY use BigInt type. Anyways, JavaScript isn't one to avoid being lossy and error prone :P
David, I think this is likely a VSCode issue. Chrome's console allows for BigInt() / 3n, etc. I think VSCode's parser just doesn't recognize it. Here's a relevant thread:
https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/95187

Answer (score 0):

If `BigInt` is undefined, then your browser is too old. Check [caniuse.com/bigint](https://caniuse.com/bigint) for browsers that support BigInts (in short: Chrome and Opera since 2018, Firefox since 2019, Safari and Edge since 2020).